# How to find steady state distribution for a continuous-state, discrete time markov chain (process)

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

I have a continuous-state discrete-time markov chain (process) and I need to find the steady-state density function. I am familiar with discrete-state markov chains, but I am not sure how to handle the continuous-state case. In particular:

1.I am not sure what conditions are necessary and sufficient for the existence of a steady-state probability, or for its uniqueness.

2.I am not sure how to actually get to steady state densities. I can write down steady state conditions, same as I would for a discrete state markov chain, but then, how do I find them?

Here are some more details. State space is the interval $[0,N]$. Transition probabilities from x to y are:

$p(x,y\in(0,N))=\frac{1}{Q}, \;\;\;\;\; p(x,y=0)=\frac{D-x}{Q}, \;\;\;\;\; p(x,y=N)=\frac{Q-D-N+x}{Q}.$

Steady state conditions obtained by imposing stationarity of distribution (using $\pi$ for steady state density/probability mass) yield

$\pi(0)=\frac{Q}{2(Q-D)}\intop_{(0,N]}\pi(y)\frac{D-y}{Q}dy,$

$\pi(N)=\frac{Q}{2(Q-D)}\intop_{(0,N]}\pi(y)\frac{Q-D-N+y}{Q}dy,$

$\pi(x|x\in(0,N))=\frac{1}{Q}\left[\pi(0)+\pi(N)+\intop_{(0,N)}\pi(y)dy\right].$

Where do I go from here?

Any help to the above, including useful references to an introductory text on continuous-state markov chains or specific results therein, is highly appreciated.

Frank

Comment: I am thinking I could impose the condition that $\pi(0)+\pi(N)+\intop_{(0,N)}\pi(y)dy=1$ to obtain $\intop_{(0,N)}\pi(y)dy$ and then leverage the symmetry of transition probabilities from and to $(0,N)$ to claim that steady state probabilities for all $x\in(0,N)$ are the same so that $\intop_{(0,N)}\pi(y)dy=N\pi$. From this I could recover all densities. Let me know what you think.

Comment: For your problem it looks like you will have a density with impulses: $\pi(x) = c1_{x \in (0,N)} + a\delta(x) + b \delta(x-N)$, where $a=P[X=0]$ and $b=P[X=N]$. Your first equation should be $$a=a(D/Q)+b(D-N)/Q + \int_{(0,N)}\underbrace{\pi(x)}_{c}\frac{D-x}{Q}dx$$ Also it looks like you are mixing notation for $p(\cdot)$ in terms of pure probabilities versus densities. It is unusual that a homework problem would be formulated incorrectly, what is the context of your problem?

Comment: Also, Markov is a name so it is "Markov chain" not "markov chain."

Comment: Not sure what $\delta$ is, a constant, a function? \\
You are right about the equation, and I realize in the above I am missing a term with $\pi(N)$ for the $\pi(0)$ expression, and a term with $\pi(0)$ in the $\pi(N)$ expression. \\
So you agree that $\pi(x)$ is constant in $(0,N)$. Is my argument above correct or you have a different one? \\
I posted my elaboration of the problem to make the post shorter so all mistakes are mines.

Comment: You are still incorrectly treating a PDF the same as a probability, it is not. An impulse function $\delta(t)$ is used to treat random variables with some continuous parts and some discrete parts. In particular $P[X=0]>0$ and $P[X=x]=0$ for $x \in (0,N)$.